# How do I make objects never overlap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a car game in pygame, but whenever I try to spawn the cars, some of them get on top of each other, how do I fix it?

Here is the code for spawning the car:

```
        if len(enemiesL) == 0:
            if len(enemiesR) == 0:
                wavelengthL += 3
            for _ in range(wavelengthL):
                enemy = EnemyL(random.randrange(160, Width/2 - 50), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["black", "blue", "brown", "darkblue", "orange", "pale", "purple", "red", "white", "yellow"]))
                enemiesL.append(enemy)
        
        if len(enemiesR) == 0:
            wavelengthR += 3
            for _ in range(wavelengthR):
                enemy = EnemyR(random.randrange(Width/2, Width-200), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["black", "blue", "brown", "darkblue", "orange", "pale", "purple", "red", "white", "yellow"]))
                enemiesR.append(enemy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a random position and evaluate if a new car at thai position is overlapping with any other car. If the car is overlapping, then discard the position. Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to evaluate if cars are overlapping.
In the following is assumed that the position of a car is (`enmey.x`, `enemy.y`) and the size of a car is (`enemy_width`, `enemy_height`):

```py
for _ in range(wavelengthL):
    while True:
        x, y = random.randrange(160, Width/2 - 50), random.randrange(-1500, -100)
    
        new_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, enemy_width, enemy_height)
        if not any(enmey for enmey in enemiesL if new_rect.colliderect(enmey.x, enmey.y, enemy_width, enemy_height)):
            break
    
    enemy = EnemyL(x, y, random.choice(["black", "blue", "brown", "darkblue", "orange", "pale", "purple", "red", "white", "yellow"]))
    enemiesL.append(enemy)
```

```py
for _ in range(wavelengthR):
    while True:
        x, y = random.randrange(Width/2, Width-200), random.randrange(-1500, -100)

        new_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, enemy_width, enemy_height)
        if not any(enmey for enmey in enemiesR if new_rect.colliderect(enmey.x, enmey.y, enemy_width, enemy_height)):
            break

    enemy = EnemyR(x, y, random.choice(["black", "blue", "brown", "darkblue", "orange", "pale", "purple", "red", "white", "yellow"]))
    enemiesR.append(enemy)
```